# Commit files using jenkins

Tags: sql, svn, jenkins

I have a pre.sql file to be executed everytime that has different content before the jenkins start building.

This brings a problem... Cannot have the same data because can generate errors, so I thought or clean the file after the build or only execute the differeces.

Someone knows or execute the differences or commit the cleaned file using jenkins?

Thanks

Comment: what is this sql file and where is it getting executed against ? How do you plan to trigger the sql file today ?

Comment: The sql file is update scripts (can be insert, delete, update or even alter tables). I was plan to trigger before the build is made

Comment: You need to break your sql file into multiple sql files, and only execute the ones that haven't been executed yet.

Comment: Is already one sql to be executed. This will only execute once and is always to be discarted forever (is just for that building)